# I have a python program. How can I integrate ROS data in it?

Tags: ros, python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a python program running perfectly. Now I need some data in the program which is being published on a rostopic. In the ros environment, I know I can get that data using rostopic echo, or save it in a text file.

Can I add something in my python program that it collects data on a ros topic and use it? All I want is that everytime my program runs, there is a new data it collects from rostopic and does the operation on it.

Right now my program is using a dummy data and I urgently need to replace it with actual data being published over a rostopic.

urgent, please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58686/i-have-a-python-program.-how-can-i-integrate-ros-data-in-it?/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-03-20

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is truly urgent, you should consider reading the [basic ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

You will probably find [Writing a Publisher and Subscriber in Python](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) helpful.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4